# CSS special values *,\0/

Tags: css

I see a css code with *, \0/ I just wonder what does it means? I guess they related to some specific browser?

```
.form_element select
{
   padding:4px;
   *padding:0px;
   padding:0px \0/;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The man jumping for joy (`\0/`) is an IE8+9 CSS hack.

The star hack (`*`), which doesn't necessarily have to be a `*` (`#` also works), is an IE6+7 hack.

Comment: He is clearly waving his arms in rage: "you should know better by now!"

Comment: IE 8+9 hack is this -> `display:none\9;`

Answer (score 6):

`\0/` targets IE8 and below, and appears after the value:

```
#id
{ padding: 0px \0/; }
```

`*` targets IE7 and below, and appears directly before the property

```
#id
{ *padding: 0px; }
```

`_` targets IE6 and below, and appears directly before the property

```
#id
{ _padding: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can read about this on http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack For `IE8, IE9` check this http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

```
#div  {color: blue\0/;} /* must go at the END of all rules */
```